# Use Selenium to run automation test with NUnit to get control of a website in a console

Tags: c#, selenium, nunit

I need to validate the data in a website but the website is open by a console (not browser, by WPF)

```
<WebBrowser bh:WebBrowserBehaviors.BindableSource="{Binding SourceUrl}"/>
```

so basically I cannot create new instance of the driver (firefox, chrome)

Any idea to control the Website?

I use 'Inspect' and try to get automation id or class name, but still didn't work well.

Comment: Can you elaborate on the statement " data in a website but the website is open by a console (not browser, by WPF)" - at the moment it makes no sense to me.

Comment: @ErkiM. sorry for the misunderstanding, basically it is a normal validation for a website using selenium. But the issue is the website is open by a console created by WPF, so I cannot create a new instance to call the url.

Comment: Hm. AFAIK you can not attach webdriver to some other process. I am not really sure about this, if you find you, do let me know.. Anyway. To my understanding, WPF is a UI technology. So do you mean, that you have an app, that has UI built with WPF and you trigger some event on that app that opens a console that opens a browser? What does that console app do? Does it open some channel, proxy or whatever? Can you open that URL in standalone browser when the console is running?

Comment: <WebBrowser bh:WebBrowserBehaviors.BindableSource="{Binding SourceUrl}"/>.. Is the browser opened inside a WPF app? Or is it a silverlight app?

Comment: The url is open inside a WPF app. Actually it can be open on a browser, but for validation purpose, I must test it on WPF app... argh... So tricky..

Answer (score 0):

You may try to get access to Document-Object-Model of the embedded browser. Dig in this direction.